# Transfer data from MS Access database to a Mysql database every time there are any changes from MS Access

Tags: mysql, database, ms-access

I would like to ask if there are any ways to transfer a data from MS Access database to a Mysql database every time there are any changes from MS Access.?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Access 2010, you may want to look into [Data Macros](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-access/archive/2009/08/13/access-2010-data-macros-similar-to-triggers.aspx) which are similar to Triggers in SQL/MySQL. This will allow you greater control over what happens when a record is changed, but if you just want a straight data synchronization then Bjoern's tools might be more effective.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this forum thread](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?65,505788,505788#msg-505788) in the mysql forum. They link alot of different ways, like

- [Access-MySQL Converter](http://www.softgalaxy.net/access-mysql/index.html#features)
- [DBSync for Access & MySQL](http://www.dbconvert.com/convert-access-to-mysql-sync.php)
- [DBLoad](http://www.dbload.com/)
- [MS Access to MySQL Database Converter](http://www.recoverybull.com/recoverybull/msaccess-mysql-db.html)
- [Access to MySQL](http://www.convert-in.com/acc2sql.htm)
- [FlySpeed](http://www.activedbsoft.com/overview-migrate-mysql.html)
- [Convert to MySQL](http://www.spectralcore.com/fullconvert/tutorials/convert-to-mysql.php)

...and a few more.

And [SQLyog](https://www.webyog.com/product/sqlyog) has an Access import, too, and it can synchronize.

Comment: @Bjoern: can i also use these tools for data synchronization?

Comment: Some of them, possibily. Most of them will be reduced to migrate from Access to MySQL though.

Comment: @Bjoern: What I am trying to do is, I would like to transfer data from ms access db to Mysql every time there are any changes from MS Access.

Comment: Well, this is not what your question says. You might want to update your question.

Comment: @Maiah_101 SQLyog has database synchronization. It has one way and two way sync.

Answer (score 1):

try the following thing to export data from MS ACCESS as CSV format and then import it in MYSQL

- Make a query on the table with only the columns you want, and save
  it.
- Select the query, and then got to File->Export (Select Save As
  "text *.txt, *cvs, etc.") and follow the prompts

I hope this would help

Comment: What I am trying to do is, I would like to transfer data from ms access db to Mysql every time there are any changes from MS Access.